# Triangles in geometry please help

Tags: geometry, triangles

Find the length of the altitude to the hypotenuse of a right triangle whose sides have lengths 6.8 and 10. The altitude to the hypotenuse separates the hypotenuse into two parts. The smaller part is 3.8. Round answer to the nearest tenth.

Comment: Where are you having problems?

Answer (score 1):

The area is $\frac{6.8\cdot 3.8}{2}$ Calculate using the hypotenuse as the base to get $\frac{10\cdot h}{2}=\frac{3.8\cdot6.8}{2}\implies h=\frac{3.8\cdot6.8}{10}$